# How to debug PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already in Play

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, hikaricp

I'm using Play 2.6 with Scala, and something in my program is eating up the connections to my Postgresql database. I keep getting:

`PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already`

In my console. I've checked my max connections with

`show max_connections;`

And it's at the default of 100, but I shouldn't be eating up this many. Any time I access the database in the application, I use the suggested:

`myDB.withConnection { conn => \... do work with SQL here ...\ }`

block, which according to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDatabase), should release the connection once it escapes the the block. I don't think anything is getting stuck in a loop, as otherwise other pieces of my code wouldn't be executing. Unfortunately, the stack trace that's printing only shows the "behind the scenes" stuff and won't show what caller is establishing the DB connection. Any ideas on how I can find the offender?

Comment: You could list current sessions and maybe it will give you idea on what is consuming connections: `select * from pg_stat_activity`

Comment: It just says it is my same application, making the connections over and over again